# Retrieve a number from each page of a paginated website

Tags: web-scraping

I have a list from approx. 36,000 URLs, ranging from https://www.fff.fr/la-vie-des-clubs/1/infos-cles to https://www.fff.fr/la-vie-des-clubs/36179/infos-cles (a few of those pages return 404 erros).

Each of those pages contains a number (the number of teams the soccer club contains). In the HTML file, the number appears as `<p class="number">5</p>.`

Is there a reasonably simple way to compile an excel or csv file with the URL and the associated number of teams as a field ?

I've tried looking into phantomJS but my method took 10 seconds to open a single webpage and I don't really want to spend 100 hours doing this. I was not able to figure out how (or whether it was at all possible) to use scraping tools such as import.io to do this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For the goal you want to achieve, I can see two solutions:

- Code it in Java: Jsoup + any CSV library

  *In a few minutes, the 36000+ urls can be downloaded easily.*
- Use a tool like [Portia](http://scrapinghub.com/portia/) from *scrapinghub.com*

  *Portia is a WYSIWYG tool quickly helping you create your project and run it. They offer a free plan which can take in charge the 36000+ links.*